# general equation of a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

The general equation of conics of the form:
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0
$$

and it is said that for a parabola $A=0$ or $C=0$ or $AC=0$ and $Bxy$ is associated with the rotations.

But for the given conic, $16x^2+8xy+y^2-74x-78y+212=0$

It seems to be a parabola even though $A=16\neq0$ and $B=1\neq0$.

What am I missing here in the general form of conics ?

What about the case with other conics ?

$A\neq C$ and $AC>0$ for ellipse

$A\neq C$ and $AC<0$ for hyperbola, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $A=0$ or $C=0$ is not quite right as you've noticed.  The discriminant $\Delta=B^2-4AC$ equals $0$ for a parabola, as with your conic.  Note that if $B=0$ then necessarily $A=0$ or $C=0$ in order for the discriminant to be zero.

Edit:  Likewise for your other rules.  Those are true only if $B=0$.  The more general rule is $\Delta<0$ is an ellipse.  $\Delta>0$ is a hyperbola.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant)

Comment: Is there another name besides $D$ that we can use for the discriminant, since $D$ is also what we're calling the coefficient of $x$?

Comment: @TannerSwett  Yes.  Thank you.  $\Delta$ is a much better choice here.

Comment: @sharding4 thnx. what about the other conics, how do i differentiate between ellipse, hyperbola etc. how can i get the complete general equation when $B\neq 0$